# How can I make configuration changes permanent?

Tags: root, configuration, virtualhost

I need to change document root in my server. I do that by opening this file:

```
nano /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Changing this:

```
<VirtualHost 46.165.242.228:80>
ServerName pronexo.net
ServerAlias mail.pronexo.net www.pronexo.net
DocumentRoot {expected documentroot path}         // here
.
.
.
```

By doing that, the document root changes and all fine. The problem is, apparently this file will be updated per week. I mean, every week I have to open that file and change the documentroot again. After 1 week, it returns to the first state, I have to edit it again, and so on ..

How can I make my change permanently?

Comment: Is this system administrated by you? Why do you have apache in `/usr/local`? Do you have a configuration management system like Puppet or Chef in place that enforces configuration?

Comment: "How can I make my change permanently?' change the original file and not the one that gets replaced. And the same question: why is apache in /usr/local?! I would expect it to be in /etc/ or in /opt/

Comment: @muru I have multiple users (cpanel account) on the same server. So I need to just change the document root of one of those accounts. That's why I modified the configuration file which is located into `usr`. Noted that when I modify it, it works as well *(documentroot changes correctly as expected)*.

Comment: @Rinzwind That ^ ... Also where is the original file located exactly?